# WPF Datagridcomboboxcolumn binding to EF query

Tags: wpf

I have a datagrid with multiple comboboxcolumns. These column binds to the viewmodel but the itemsource for each column is stored in a  database and the plan is to populate these using EF and linq (`list<string>'s`).

Problem is that I can't find a way to set a name for the combobox column so in the loaded event I can set each columns itemsource by saying

```
usercontrol_loaded () {
  List<string> mylistA = (from a in context.table 
                         select a.name).toList<string();

  datagrid.colA.itemsource = mylistA;
}
```

Datagrid:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Fruit" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Fruit}"/>    
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Veg" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Veg}"/>
</datagrid>
```

Note: all code is handwritten so please ignore its mistakes/incompleteness!!

The datagrid itself is in a datatemplate which is loaded into a contentcontrol.

Answer (score 0):

You set the name in XAML:

```
x:Name="colA"
```